# How can I fix a Runtime Error for a Ruby on Rails app using a Windows Operating System?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run my homepage of my rails app in the browser, but when I run the page I get a runtime error saying that "Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES5. Please install node.js".

How can I fix this error?

[image: Runtime Error in Pages#home]

Here's my Gem file:

```
 source 'http://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 5.0.0.2'
```

Here's what returned on my command line:

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0
.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-01-24 14:32:37] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-24 14:32:37] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
[2015-01-24 14:32:37] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4284 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-24 14:37:02 -0500
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (41.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 320ms (Views: 235.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/pages/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-24 14:41:10 -0500
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 419ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES5. Please i
nstall node.js.
  (in c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/stylesheets/application.cs
s)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Pinteresting</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolink
s-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => tr
ue %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_ht
ml_erb__829465221_47419968'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
 (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within
 rescues/layout (178.0ms
```

)

What's the correct way to install the node.js gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its not a gem, you have to install node.js from http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 4):

After installing the [node.js](http://nodejs.org),  the issue might not be get fixed at once. You need to reboot the system once or twice to set the update and the issue will be solved. Please refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571986/application-css-scss-causing-issue-with-rails-4).