# Application.css.scss causing issue with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i've been learning ruby on rails and i decided to add some style to my new posts page on a myrubyblog app. Everything was working. After a few days i decided to import scss from the posts.scss file into the application.css.scss and well i get this error

```
RuntimeError in Home#index
Showing c:/Sites/myrubyblog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES5. Please install node.js.
  (in c:/Sites/myrubyblog/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
Extracted source (around line #0):
```

After removing my application.css.scss file, the pages were working. Upon removing the actual scss code and leaving the application.css.scss the page began to give problems again. I decided to leave the application.css.scss file deleted. This for some reason allows for the styles i set in it to show up even though the stylesheet itself has been deleted.

Comment: can you add the code from the line that was giving an error?

Comment: Looks like you need to install node.js, must be trying to compile something on the fly that it can't

Comment: i did install node.js but nothing changed :/

Comment: @Josh oh and there is no code from the line giving the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing Node.js seemed to have worked. I just had to reboot.... twice...
Thx guys i guess.